# Regex to match grades

Tags: java, regex

I have an array

```
String[] grades = new String[]{"D","C-","C","C+","B-","B","B+","A-","A","A+"};
```

I want to check if a string is one of these values.

I could loop through the array to accomplish this, but I want to do it through regex.

Comment: Can we see some sample string?

Comment: Could we see some question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The regex is rather simple:

```
[A-C][+-]?|D
```

The first part says that `A` through `C` could be followed by an optional plus or minus; the second part allows a `D` by itself.

> I could loop through the array to accomplish this

You could also use `contains()`, to do it without a loop:

```
if (Arrays.asList(grades).contains(grade)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Do I need to add back slashes in order to escape anything in java? `String regex = "[A-C][+-]?|D"` is this fine?

Comment: @atripathi I don't think you need to escape anything, the regex should be fine as is. Take a look: [link to a silly example on ideone](http://ideone.com/hBjRLY).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight How can keep validation for taking input as only A or B or C, single character?

Comment: You may want to modify it like this:
   [B-D][+-]?|A[-]?|E
This disallows A+, and allows E (which some schools use to indicate a failing grade instead of F).